# Automatically converting Excel Files to Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-drive-api, scripting-language

I have a google account that uses the save emails and attachments add-on.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-emails-and-attachmen/nflmnfjphdbeagnilbihcodcophecebc?hl=en

The email account only receives excel sheets as attachments, and those are saved to a specific folder automatically.

Is it possible to have those sheets converted automatically to google sheets upon save (or after save).  Currently, I have to open the file with google sheets to convert it.

I have tried setting the folder to Convert uploaded files to Google Docs editor format, but that doesn't work for this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Eric

Answer (score 1):

if you're wishing to do this with the Drive API, then you can do so using the examples given in [Upload Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads), see the section headed *Importing to Google Docs types*. Essentially, by setting the source file MIME type to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` and that of the new file to `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`, this indicates that the conversion is required on upload.